How does the 4th trumpet (in Revelation 8:12) happen after the 6th seal (in Revelation 6:12)?
In Revelation 6:12, the sun becomes black and the stars fall to the earth, with the sky receding. In Revelation 8:12 with the 4th trumpet, the sun is just darkened 1/3 as well as the stars.
So which happened first? And how do we reconcile these two events hermeneutically?

Hello Pete - welcome to BHSX - thanks for joining our group.  Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to better understand how this site is different.

Good question. Up-voted +1.

You want to know which of those two events happened first. The chronological aspect of the entire book of Revelation will remain a confusion until it is seen that it repeats, seven times, events from the time of Christ's first coming through to his second coming. This is to prepare and enable every generation of Christians from the writing of Revelation until he comes to endure whatever tribulations and plagues afflict their generation, to keep strong in faith that Christ will suddenly appear. They are warned again and again in Revelation about the build-up of woes increasing, building up to a huge global deception the great red dragon will bring upon earth (via his earthly agencies). Only Christians who grasp the principles explained in those seven-times-repeated sequences of events will see how they are worked out in their generation.
Try reading the whole of the book of Revelation according to the following 'divisions' or 'openings':
1st opening - Rev. 1:9 to the end of chapter 3.
2nd opening - Rev. 4:1 to the end of chapter 6.
3rd opening - Rev. 7:1 to end of chapter 11.
4th opening - Rev. 12:1 to end of chapter 14.
5th opening - Rev. 15:1 to end of chapter 16.
6th opening - Rev. 17:1 to end of chapter 19.
7th opening - Rev. 19:1 to chapter 22 verse 5.
Notice how the same events are reiterated, but with more detail added each time? Spot the basic principles and then how those principles are expanded? As explained here:

"Each division or opening in the Book of the Revelation of Jesus
Christ, including the seventh, discloses principles governing the
entire age, from the birth, death and resurrection, and ascension of
Christ, until his coming again. In some openings, where several
principles are enunciated having a common denominator, such as the
seven churches, the four horsemen, or the seven trumpets, all of
these figures reveal principles in and of themselves applicable
throughout the age.
Though such figures are manifested in a larger context, each one
enlightens the saints during the whole of their present pilgrimage.
Where this is the case, for example, with the seven trumpets in the
third opening, chapters 7-11, although the whole division speaks to
the entire age, nevertheless each trumpet, having that in common with
every other trumpet, sounds so as to reveal an integral principle in
itself applicable to the entire duration of the time between the first
and the second coming of Christ... Thus it is that the narrative
repetitively returns to the beginning." The Revelation of Jesus
Christ, John Metcalfe, p. 543, first published 1998.
http://www.johnmetcalfepublishingtrust.co.uk/contact_us.htm (Emphasis
mine, and note that 'the six seals' could be included after it.)

The six seals: Concluding the second section of Revelation, chapter 6 records the breaking of the first six seals. The first four seals are distinguished by certain things in common; the four mystical horses signify divine powers, and not single events. The fifth seal reveals the souls of them that were slain for the word of God, and their testimony, under heaven's altar. The world treated (and continues to treat) them as it did Christ. Those under the altar must patiently and faithfully wait until the horses rides are done. When they are finally reined in, the wrath of God shall be poured out from heaven on all who hated the Man on the white horse, and the saints.
Then comes the 6th seal, Rev. 6:12-17. The number seven recurs - seven things are brought to final judgment - perfect judgment. Thus, the great day of wrath has come. But there is only one 'last day' - not seven! This is how we know that each of the seven openings ends at that last day, at the end of the age.
The seven trumpets - The first four trumpets afflict the earth, sea, waters and heaven. The remaining trumpets directly affect men, being accompanied by a 'woe'. The graphic pictures do not describe single events. The soundings of the trumpets should be seen as bring continuous throughout the age. Even the seventh - the last - trump, the Last Judgment, should be viewed in this way in the sense that the final judgment is the climax of the continuous and parallel six partial judgments.
Viewed symbolically, it is as if there is a continuous and ever-increasing crescendo of these trumpets, which seems as a growing cacophony on earth, but is a harmonious concerto in heaven, coming to its climax with the seventh. The sound in heaven reverberates on earth throughout time. But not literally! This is all symbolic! There is no actual third part of sun, moon and stars darkened. The symbolic, spiritual darkness precedes the increasing "Woe, woe, woe" that the angel declares is coming with the following three trumpet blasts (vs. 12-13).
Answer: The two events are harmonised chronologically and hermeneutically once the seven 'openings' are identified and the Revelation read in light of that 'key'.

First off, it’s probably necessary to acknowledge that the exact means by which the seals, trumpets, and bowls will play out is not explicitly given to us in the scriptures. However, it’s worth considering why a strictly chronological reading might not be the most fitting approach.
Why couldn’t it be a simple, linear sequence of events? Well, when we examine each series, they all appear to culminate in a cataclysmic event that alters the earth as we know it and ushers in the establishment of Christ’s kingdom on earth.
Sixth Seal (Revelation 6:12-17)

"And the sun became black as sackcloth of hair, and the moon became as blood... and the [inhabitants of earth] said to the mountains and rocks, Fall on us, and hide us from the face of him that sitteth on the throne, and from the wrath of the Lamb. For the great day of his wrath is come; and who shall be able to stand?"

Seventh Trumpet (Revelation 11:15-19)

"The kingdoms of this world are become the kingdoms of our Lord, and of his Christ; and he shall reign for ever and ever...”

Seventh Bowl (Revelation 16:17-21)

"… a great voice out of the temple of heaven, from the throne, saying, It is done... And there were voices, and thunders, and lightnings; and there was a great earthquake... And every island fled away, and the mountains were not found."

Each of these series appears to reference the same ultimate event, suggesting that they may not be sequential, but rather there seems to be overlapping elements of each. This makes a simple chronological reading less likely. When it comes to how exactly they may overlap, there are several possible explanations where each has fairly strong arguments. One I want to propose is paralleled in Joshua regarding the fall of Jericho. (Perhaps the “Jericho Theory”? I’m sure I am not the first person to draw the parallel here, but I like the name).
In Joshua 6:1-5, God speaks to Joshua and tells him how to conquer Jericho:

… ye shall compass the city, all ye men of war, and go round about the city once. Thus shalt thou do six days. And seven priests shall bear before the ark seven trumpets of rams' horns: and the seventh day ye shall compass the city seven times, and the priests shall blow with the trumpets. And it shall come to pass, that when they make a long blast with the ram's horn, and when ye hear the sound of the trumpet, all the people shall shout with a great shout; and the wall of the city shall fall down flat, and the people shall ascend up every man straight before him.

And this is precisely what they did. For six days they circled about Jericho once per day blowing horns, then on the seventh day they circled the city seven times blowing the horn seven times. Upon this final time, the Israelites shout a great shout and the city falls.
As we see in many instances in Scripture, the events of the Old Testament serve as shadows or typologies of what is to come. The author of Hebrews explains that the things of the Law  are a pattern or shadow of heavenly things (Hebrews 8:5). Similarly, Paul in Colossians 2:17 writes that the Old Testament rituals were "a shadow of things to come.” These references suggest that the pattern we see in the conquest of Jericho can be seen as a symbolic preview of future events unfolding. Why would God’s instruction here be different? At the very least, I think it’s tough to argue there isn’t some sort of symbolism at play in how He instructed them to conquer Jericho.
As to why I think it is clearly a typology of the end times events, we see multiple parallels between Jericho’s fall and the events of Revelation (and accompanying end times passages). To recap and name a few:

Various Series of Sevens

Jericho: Seven days, seven marches, seven trumpets (Joshua 6:4-15).
End Times: Seven seals, seven trumpets, and seven bowls (Revelation 6-16).


Two Individuals Sent into the Land

Jericho: Two spies are sent into Jericho to witness God’s plan and prepare the way for the Israelites (Joshua 2:1).
End Times: Two witnesses are sent to proclaim the gospel during the tribulation (Revelation 11:3-12).


Great Shout

Jericho: After the seventh trumpet blast on the seventh day, the Israelites shout, and the walls of Jericho fall (Joshua 6:20).
End Times: Christ’s return is accompanied by a great shout, signaling the final victory (1 Thessalonians 4:16, Revelation 19:6-7).


No Wickedness Is Left Alive

Jericho: All of Jericho is destroyed, except for Rahab and her family (Joshua 6:24-25).
End Times: With Christ’s arrival, the wicked are destroyed, and only the righteous remain (2 Thessalonians 1:7-10, Revelation 20:11-15).


Only the Righteous Remain

Jericho: Rahab and her household are spared because of her faith (Joshua 2:12-13, Joshua 6:25).
End Times: The righteous, those who are faithful to Christ, inherit the kingdom and the new earth (Matthew 25:34, Revelation 21:1-4).



With all of this being said, it is at least worth considering that this may very well be foreshadowing of the final judgment period to come. If it is so, it would seem to follow that there is chronology but also overlap within the seals, trumpets and bowls. It seems as if the Sixth Seal could very well open and within it the Seven Trumpets blow, and the Seventh Trumpet culminating into the Seven Bowls of God’s wrath ultimately being poured out. Though not directly within the topic, I find this also to be a very compelling example that points to a post-tribulational rapture.
Anyway, I hope this can be helpful or at the very least thought provoking to anyone who may read.
God bless.

Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics. One thing to check when we consider Old Testament events as shadows and/or types of Christ is if any of the New Testament authors showed these analogies. Another possibility is the shadow we think we see that is a likeness of something from the Old Testament referenced as a type or shadow to the New Testament is really a pattern of how God relates to humans, which can be repeated often enough to be visible in both Old and New Testaments. I think this is the case in Jericho's fall.

@RobCallicotte I see your point, but I don't believe these typologies are either/or situations. They are both: a reflection of how God relates to humanity and a prophetic image of what is to come. Hebrews 11:39-40 paints this picture, showing various OT events/people (Jericho and Rahab included) as a promise fulfilled, but not the greatest promise to come, which they were pointing toward. Revelation 10:7 makes this clear: "But in the days of the voice of the seventh angel, when he shall begin to sound, the mystery of God should be finished, as he hath declared to his servants the prophets."

The Revelation is divided into three repeating sections for a reason.
The seals are the Testament, as in a "last will and testament," or the New Testament (put in force when Christ died). The book of the testament, or scroll, depending on how the Greek reads, is sealed with seven seals. No one in heaven or earth was able to open the seals until the lion of Judah prevailed, a lamb as though it had been slain. (Rev. 5:1-7)
With each seal that the lamb opened, the events contained in the scroll were revealed, and not necessarily in order. Note in 6:1 that it says that he opened "one of the seals" as opposed to the "first" seal. The others, chronologically, may simply refer to the order of being opened as opposed to the order numerically or positionally. So, rather than opening the first, second, third, fourth, etc., he opened "one of the seals," then opened a second seal, and then a third, and a fourth, etc. This might explain the difference in order of events between the seals, trumpets, and bowls.
With the seals opened and the contents of the document revealed, the trumpeters prepare to sound. And their job is to announce the contents of the Testament, and those things that are about to come to pass.
The bowls are the execution of the seals.
So, the events are revealed and read, heralded and announced, and then executed. The only one where the order of events matters is the bowls. The events can be read in any order. The events can be announced in any order. But their execution happened in the order they happened.
Hope that answers your question.

I am not sure there is any need to reconcile the 6th seal and the 4th trumpet as they describe different events.  However, let me offer some very general comments out the progression of the seals and trumpets.
7 Seals
According to Jesus in Matt 24:29-31 the darken of the sun, and falling stars occurs just after the great tribulation and immediately before the return of the Son of man (Jesus) in the clouds of heaven. This appears to be confirmed by Rev 6:15-17.
Lastly note that many of the seals fall on one quarter of the earth/trees etc.
7 Trumpets
The seven trumpets appear to be a series a partial judgements on the wicked by noticing that they fall on the unsealed as per the fifth and sixth seal.  The object of each trumpet-plague also appears in the reverse order of creation week events; they the trumpets appear to be the undoing of creation in some sense.
Lastly, note that many of the trumpet-judgements fall on one third of the earth.

The key is understanding that the seventh seal is made up of seven trumpets, and that the seventh trumpet is made up of the seven last plagues.
In the case mentioned in the Title question, the 4th trumpet is part of the 7th seal, which of course happens after the 6th seal.
Seven seals:

Religious deception (Revelation 6:1-2; compare Matthew 24:4-25)
War (Revelation 6:3-4; compare Matthew 24:6-7)
Famine (Revelation 6:5-6; compare Matthew 24:7)
Disease epidemics (Revelation 6:7-8; compare Matthew 24:7)
Tribulation and persecution (Revelation 6:9-11; compare Matthew 24:8-22)
Heavenly signs (Revelation 6:12-17; compare Matthew 24:29)
Seven trumpets:

Destruction of vegetation (Revelation 8:7)
Devastation of oceans and sea life (Revelation 8:8-9)
Devastation of rivers and fresh water (Revelation 8:10-11)
Sun, moon and stars darkened (Revelation 8:12)
Torturous human afflictions (Revelation 9:1-12)
Enormous military destruction (Revelation 9:13-19)
Seven last plagues (Revelation 15:1; Revelation 16:1-21):

Sores upon those with the mark of the Beast.
Death of the sea.
Rivers become blood.
Blasphemers are scorched.
The Beast's kindom is plunged into darkness.
The Euphrates dries up.
"It is done": earthquakes, hail, destruction.





— Adapted from The Story Flow of the Book of Revelation.

In ch6, the blackness of the sun, the redness of the moon, and the apparent disappearance of the stars could all be the effects of atmospheric pollution.
This is the kind of phenomenon which could happen more than once.
As for the order of events, Revelation offers a clear sequence in which the world-shaking events of ch6 are followed by a distinct pause in the action (ch7 v1), explained as an interval to allow the sealing to take place. There is "silence in heaven" (ch8 v1). That is, as I understand it, there is a continuing pause in the operation of God's wrath upon the earth. When the silence in heaven ends with thunder, lightning and voices (ch8 v5), that is the signal that the operation of God's wrath is about to be resumed (v6). So the trumpets are announcing a fresh set of catastrophes.

Yes, we are given a hard timeline of seven years in which the 7 Trumpets are released, with two more pauses/woes in between the 5th and 6th, then again between the 6th and 7th.  How condensed or stretched out the timeline is on either side of that seven years isn’t known to us.
